# Error in Processing Request Code 502 Text : OK

Tags: phpmyadmin

somebody know how to fix this??
I've search for the same problem and it doesn't work.
PHPmyAdmin work fine before.

message shows:

Error in Processing request
Error Code : 502
Error Text : OK

Comment: What are you trying to do when the error occurs? Is it when you log in or try a specific action? Any hints in the webserver error log? Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: @Isaac Bennetch
it is show up when I choose PhpMyAdmin in Xampp, and when I chose any other menu, the notification showing up and stuck there. Unfortunately I not found any hint in error log. so confuse.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the error occurs with other menus within phpMyAdmin (such as Databases, SQL, Users) or menus within XAMPP (Status, Security, Webalizer) ?

Comment: menu in Xampp is okay, but menu in PhpMyAdmin blocked by the notification.